# Building a Python Tkinter GUI without enumerated global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to have tabs in a notebook and have a way to enter something into a text box at the bottom of the screen and then it to be echoed back out to me. I know I'm on the right path and maybe having it all in separate functions isn't a good idea I was able to get the `<return>` event to work but just printed out to terminal and not the label within the new tab (think like Skype or another messaging app with tabs, that's basically what I am going for).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

tCount=0

def do_command(event):
    text = Text(root)
    text.pack()
    tabControl.add(text, text=entry.get())
    

def make_new_tab(event):
    global tCount
    global oLabel
    global entry
    if tabControl.select() == tabControl.tabs()[-1]:
        tCount+=1
        index = len(tabControl.tabs())-1
        frame = tk.Frame(tabControl)
        oLabel = tk.Label(frame)
        entry_var = tk.StringVar()
        entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=entry_var,width=root.winfo_vrootwidth())
        entry.bind("<Return>", lambda event: do_command)
        entry.pack(side='bottom', anchor='w')
        tabControl.insert(index, frame, text='tCount')
        tabControl.select(index)

def setup():
    global tabControl
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500')
    root.title("Tinkering With Tkinter")
    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
    frame = tk.Frame(tabControl)
    tabControl.add(frame, text="+")
    tabControl.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", make_new_tab)
    tabControl.bind("<Configure>", )

    tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")



    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
```

I dislike the way I have the global variables. Is there some way to do this without using them like this? Maybe in an array?

Comment: Without using global. It is better to manipulate all widgets outside of functions.